# I want to customise devise gem's controllers, is it possible and how to do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there a way to customise the devise controllers , as we can modify the devise views using the "rails g devise:views" generator command. ??
Ok purpose here is to create a statistics table's row for the current user as soon as a user is registered.
I have a user statistics maintained for every user.I just want to trigger the create method of the userstats controller in the background when a user sign-up for my web app.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own controllers inheriting from Devise's.

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

Then you tell devise to use that controller:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }
```

And copy your views from devise/sessions, to admin/sessions.

You can read it here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 2):

Or simply do this:

```
rails generate devise:controllers Admin
```

Answer (score 1):

or copy the devise controllers from where they are now to your app. This is what I did with RVM:

```
cp -R ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@my_gemset/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/controllers/* my_rails_app/app/controllers/
```

Comment: Inheritable controllers were not introduced into Devise until version 1.1, so this solution seems to be the most efficient way to go when you're stuck with Devise 1.0 for Rails 2.3