# Using Ruby on Rails, what is the quickest method to create user registration and activation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, user-registration

I wonder if it can be done in 10 to 15 minutes?

Is there a quickest method?

Is the most elegant and robust solution possibly a different one?

Answer (score 5):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is the way to go. The README should get you started in 10 minutes. It shouldn't be really hard to use it in your Rails3 app.

Comment: I agree, Devise really is the quickest and best solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing your code from the scratch, I would also suggest giving [prologue](https://github.com/quickleft/prologue) or [railswizard](http://railswizard.org/) a try. Otherwise my vote goes for using devise :)

Answer (score 1):

For a Rails3 App definitely Devise ;). But one limitation killing me on devise is that I'm yet to find a way to customize the devise's controllers. I have raised a question this and yet to get some answers [I want to customise devise gem's controllers, is it possible and how to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112030/i-want-to-customise-devise-gems-controllers-is-it-possible-and-how-to-do) . If your requirement is as simple as user registration and complete authentication throughout M , V and C stacks then Devise is the best solution for now :)